# Add Javascript function to global scope

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I have an emscripten application.  I have a javascript file that has a function definition.  I load that file into a string and then call `emscripten_run_script` on it. Then, I try to call that function later using some inline `EM_ASM` call, but it says the function definition can't be found.

```
    std::ifstream file("script.js"); // script.js has "someFunc" defined
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    emscripten_run_script( str.c_str() );

     // the below give error "someFunc not defined"
     EM_ASM({
        someFunc();
    });
```

However, if I load that javascript file into a string and then append the string with the call to the function

```
    std::ifstream file("script.js"); // script.js has "someFunc" defined
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    auto combinedStr = str + "someFunc();";

    emscripten_run_script( combinedStr.c_str() ); // works fine
```

How can I add a javascript function defined in a file to global scope to be used later on?

The javascript file looks like this:

```
function someFunc()
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tests I've done this seems to work, which should be equivalent to what you've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int main()
{
    char script[] = "someFunc = function() {"
                    "console.log(\"hello\");"
                    "};";

    emscripten_run_script(script);

    EM_ASM({
        someFunc();
    });
}
```

Is your `script.js` declaring the function to be local in scope (via `var someFunc = function(){...};` or somesuch)? `emscripten_run_script` isn't exactly like JavaScripts `eval` and local variables only exist within the scope of `emscripten_run_script`.

Comment: Thanks, simply changing from "function someFunc()" to "someFunc = function()" did the trick!